# Scoping an associations on JSONAPI endpoint in Rails serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, json-api

Is there a way to scope this endpoint (User#Show) on my Rails API, maybe in the serializer? I want to return only the user's last delivery_address, not all of them. I don't want it to effect non API requests.

`def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_with @user, include: ['delivery_addresses']
end`

I have tried things like 'delivery_address.last', but that doesn't work and I can't find an explanation on the AMS repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your serializer specify `attribute :last_delivery` and add the method `def last_delivery; object.delivery_addresses.last; end` if I understand your question